# Copy a selected column in shiny into a new dataframe to work with

Tags: r, shiny

I have CSV Files who are not the same. Each Study I have to do has other quantity and names of columns.

So I have write an shiny app and have no problem to import the first table (data).
But for capability analysis I will choose the column in dropdown and copy into a new dataframe `data1` and filter for NA values (later on dates and so on).

[image: Workflow]

[image]

I have try some ways but no one shows me the data of chosen column in `tabPanel Daten`
but always I get the `Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

[image]

Here is my actual code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(markdown)
library(tidyr)
#============================================================================
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Prozessanalyse"),
#============================================================================
    # Seitliches Menü 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(width = 3,
            #Funktion zur Dateiauswahl zum hochladen
            fileInput("Datei", "CSV Datei wählen", accept = ".csv",
                      buttonLabel = "Suchen...",
                      placeholder = "Datei wählen"),
            #Auswahl der Daten Spalte
            uiOutput('dropdown'),
            actionButton(inputId = "trans",label="Übernehmen"),
            #Eingabe Nominal Maß
            numericInput("Nom", "Nominal:", ""),
            #Eingabe Obere Soll-Grenze
            numericInput("OSG", "Obere Soll-Grenze:", ""),
            #Eingabe Untere Soll-Grenze
            numericInput("USG", "Untere Soll-Grenze:", ""),
            br(),
            #Beenden Button
            actionButton(inputId = "Ende", label = "Beenden")
        ),
#============================================================================
        mainPanel(
          #Menüband oben
      tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Kopfaten",
                  withMathJax(),
                  h3("Kopfdaten hier eingeben"),
                  #Kopfdatenfelder
                  textInput("head1", "Name", ""),
                  textInput("head2", "Teile-Nr.", ""),
                  textInput("head3", "Teilebezeichnung", ""),
                  textInput("head4", "Zeichnungs-Nr.", ""),
                  textInput("head5", "Zeichnungs Index", ""),
                  textInput("head6", "Positions-Nr.", ""),
                  selectInput("Art","Merkmalsart",c("Durchmesser", "Abstand", "Gewicht", "Koordinate")
                              ),
                  #Evtl. soll hier nach datum gefiltert werden können
                  dateRangeInput("head7",
                                 label="Auswertung von",
                                 format="dd.mm.yyyy",
                                 language="de",
                                 separator = "bis"
                                 )
                  ),
#============================================================================
          tabPanel("Analyse",
                   h3("Prozessanalyse"),
                   p("Hier sollen die Auswertungen mit Diagrammen angezeigt werden.")
                   ),
                  
          tabPanel("Daten",
                   h3("Datenmanipulation"),
                   p("Hier soll die Datentabelle angezeigt und bearbeitet werden koennen"),
                   tableOutput("data1")
                   ),
          tabPanel("Original-Daten",
                  h3("Datenmanipulation"),
                  p("Hier soll die Datentabelle angezeigt und bearbeitet werden koennen"),
                  tableOutput("original")
                  ),
          tabPanel("Importeinstellungen",
                   p("Einstellungen für die Import-Datei"),
                   #Kopzeilenabfrage
                   checkboxInput("header", "Kopfzeile vorhanden", TRUE),
                   #Auswahl Dezimalzeichen
                   radioButtons(inputId = 'dformat', label = 'Dateiformat', choices = c(Excel='1', CSV='2'), selected = '2'),
                   #Auswahl Dezimalzeichen
                   radioButtons(inputId = 'dez', label = 'Dezimalzeichen', choices = c(Komma=',', Punkt=''), selected = ','),
                   #Auswahl der Trennzeichen
                   radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Komma=',',Semikolon=';',Tab='\t', Leerzeichen=''), selected = ';')
                   
          )
               )
    )
  )
)
#============================================================================

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#============================================================================
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output){
  #Befehl für den Beenden-Button
    observe({
      if (input$Ende == "1") 
        stopApp()
    })
#============================================================================
#Lade CSV Datei
  data <-reactive({
    req(input$Datei, input$header, file.exists(input$Datei$datapath))
    read.csv2(input$Datei$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = input$header)
  })
  output$original <-renderTable({
    req(data())
    data()
  })
#============================================================================
    #Auslesen der Zeilen Namen für die Dropdownauswahl
    output$dropdown <-renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput("cols","Datenspalte wählen", names(data()))
  })
#============================================================================
  #Funktion für das Übernehemen der gewählten Spalte in das neue Dataframe
    
  output$data1 <- renderTable({
    req(input$cols)
    subset(data,input$cols == input$cols) 
  })
  
  #Bereinigen der Daten (Löschen von Rows mit "Na")
  
}
#============================================================================
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

After Comment from @phil I have changed the programm line to

````
```output$data1 <- renderTable({
req(input$cols)
subset(data(),input$cols == input$cols)
})```
````

and now the Table will be displayed.
Only the choosen dropdown Column should be copied to `data1`

[image: Displayed Table with all columns]

Changing the code to proposal from `@phil` with `dplyr` is the solution I have looking for.

````
```output$data1 <- renderTable({
req(input$cols)
select(data(), all_of(input$cols))
})```
````

[image: solution]

Comment: `subset(data,input$cols == input$cols)` should be `subset(data(),input$cols == input$cols)`

Comment: Actually, it's not clear what you mean by `input$cols == input$cols` within `subset()`

Comment: Thank you, the clamps for data() helped that the table will shown on Tabpanel "Daten". But the requst is, that only the dropdown choosed column will be shown.

Comment: `subset()` removes rows. If you want to remove columns, you can use `select()` from the `dplyr` package: `select(data(), all_of(input$cols))`

Comment: Thank you @Phil you have helped me very well